Can one fulfill the obligation of eating a כזית of פת on the first night of Sukkos with cake?
There is an obligation to eat a כזית of פת on the first night of Sukkos. (Orach Chaim 639:3)
Can one fulfill that obligation with something that is Mezonos, such as cake?

It shouldn't be any worse than the obligation on the first night of Pesach (from which it is derived) where most Jews don't insist on bread proper but rather eat a cracker (פת הבא בכיסנין)

שערי תשובה אורח חיים תרל"ט:ג'
ומ"מ היכי שבאמת קבע על לחם זה דבכה"ג מהני לברכה אף לפי המח"ב נראה דבכה"ג שפיר יוצא י"ח לילה הראשונה ג"כ וצ"ע בזה

Note cake is not always mezonos. There are different kinds of "mezonos" foods, including some whose blessing varies with the context.

@DoubleAA U dont wash and make hamotzie on matzah regardless of if you're eating a substantial amount?

Machlokes reishonim
